# How can I add a border to arrow in react-tooltip v5?

Tags: react-tooltip

How can I add a border to arrow in [react-tooltip v5](https://react-tooltip.com/docs/getting-started)?

When I specify a border using classNameArrow, it does not work as [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bY1YJ.png).

I want to display the border like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdLWx.png).

I would also like to consider when the Tooltip place is also other than top.

Here is a [sample code](https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-aj-efs71q?file=/src/App.js).

Comment: Just for reference [https://github.com/ReactTooltip/react-tooltip/issues/998](https://github.com/ReactTooltip/react-tooltip/issues/998)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just do:

```
.example-arrow {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom:0px;
  border-right:0px;
}
```

Add `margin-top: -1px;` too if you want to make it look nicer.

The arrow is just a rotated square, so you have to set a different styles (try using with border-left and border-top) for other positions.

Comment: thanks.
However, that way, when Tooltip's place is other than top, it goes wrong.

Comment: I added a bit of explanation for the other positions. Try setting different classnames for different positions, each using a different `border-bottom` `border-left` `border-right` and `border-top` combination.

Comment: That method may be difficult because of the automatic change of place in some locations.
I will consider eliminating the border. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the CSS class you need.

```
.example-arrow {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}
```

Turns out the classNameArrow is by default a box (square) that's been rotated clockwise by 45 degrees.

Comment: thanks.
However, that way, when Tooltip's place is other than top, it goes wrong.

Comment: @Yusa You're right, I haven't thought about that. Have you tried setting both tooltip and arrow borders to transparent? Doing that makes it look pretty good to me and might be how it was intended to be used.

Comment: Maybe that would be better...
Thank you!